# Spring define bean to auto-scan

Tags: spring, autowired

I have a `@Component`-annotated class which has several auto-wired dependencies. I don't want to auto-scan that package, as it has a lot of other classes that I don't want initialized.

I can add these to a `@Configuration` as a `@Bean`, however I don't want to lose the ability to have things auto-wired and me not actually changing the configuration in all places they are configured. In other words, I don't want to be listing all the dependencies for the above component manually.

I know I can use filters for component scanning, but these are cumbersome when there are a lot of classes in different packages to be picked in the above manner.

Is there a way to tell Spring to add and auto-wire a specific class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see from the [JavaDoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ComponentScan.html), the `@ComponentScan` annotation has several different ways you can register components.  If you don't want to use filters, probably the easiest thing to do would be to selectively add classes and sub-packages to scan, rather than the top level of your application.  For example:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(
    basePackages = { "me.myorg.myapp.services", "me.myorg.myapp.web" },
    basePackageClasses = { me.myorg.myapp.config.MyDbConfig.class })
public class MyAppConfig { ... }
```

It is also worth pointing out that you can create a lot of public static configuration subclasses.  These will be ignored by component scanning, but can be imported as normal into other config classes.  This can be useful in the above scenario, if you want to just scan every package, but then selectively scan or import subclasses:

```
public class BaseConfig {

    @Configuration
    public static class DbConfigA {...}

    @Configuration
    public static class DbConfigB {...}

}

@Configuration
@ComponentScan(
    basePackages = { "me.myorg.myapp" },
    basePackageClasses = { DbConfigA.class })
public class MyAppConfig { ... }
```

Comment: Thanks for the two solutions, I think this will work great for what I need.